Continued fractions inspired propositions: What do these have in common in terms of truth values?
Suppose a single logic binary relation (i.e., any of those in $\{\lor, \land, \to, \leftrightarrow\}$) were to take the place of addition in a continued fraction, with $\neg$ as taking multiplicative inverse and the values in the fraction being propositions. For example, for $\lor$, a "continued fraction" would be
$$[A; B, C]_\lor:=A\lor\neg(B\lor\neg C).$$
(Here the notation $[A; B, C]_\lor$ is designed to match that of continued fractions of natural numbers.)
The Question:

What do the continued fractions $[A_0; A_1, \dots, A_n]_\sim$ have in common in terms of truth values, if we fix propositions $A_0, A_1, \dots, A_n$, where $\sim\in\{\lor, \land, \to, \leftrightarrow\}$?

Thoughts:
This seems intractable for me for distinct $A_i$ for large $n$, so consider first $n=1$ with $A=A_0=A_1$:
$$\begin{align}
[A;A]_\lor&=A\lor\neg A\equiv \top,\\
[A;A]_\land&=A\land\neg A\equiv \bot,\\
[A;A]_\to&=A\to\neg A\equiv \neg A\lor\neg A\equiv \neg A,\\
[A;A]_\leftrightarrow&=A\leftrightarrow \neg A\equiv\bot.
\end{align}$$
Conclusion: $[A;A]_\land=[A;A]_\leftrightarrow$.
What about distinct $A=A_0, B=A_1$? Well . . .
$$\begin{align}
[A;B]_\lor&=A\lor\neg B\equiv B\to A,\\
[A;B]_\land&=A\land\neg B\equiv\neg(A\to B),\\
[A;B]_\to&=A\to\neg B,\\
[A;B]_\leftrightarrow&=A\leftrightarrow \neg B.
\end{align}$$
This doesn't tell me much. Let's do truth tables:
$$\begin{array}{cc|cccc}
A & B & [A;B]_\lor & [A;B]_\land & [A;B]_\to & [A;B]_\leftrightarrow
\\
\hline
T & T & T & F & F & F\\
T & F & T & T & T & T\\
F & T & F & F & T & T\\
F & F & T & F & T & F
\end{array}.$$
There doesn't appear to be any clear relationship here. I suspect this to be the case for distinct $A_i$ for $n\ge 2$ therefore, but who knows?
Perhaps the simpler question would be the same as The Question but for $A_i=A$ for all $i$, then.
This seems mostly an exercise in de Morgan's Laws.

$\require{MnSymbol}$ A similar question could be asked for the schema $$\ulcorner [A_0; A_1, \dots, A_n]_\sim\urcorner.$$
